# How do I upgrade Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 17.10, tpm

I was trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10, and I used the Ubuntu Software / updates, but it gave an error. Also my laptop has logged me out of sessions/restart from Ubuntu login screen twice.

Is this due to not being on 18.04? Also I have used `sudo` to add Mint desktop repository as an option.

I see this error as shown in the photo:

```
tpw tpw0: A TPM error (325) occurred stopping the TPM
```

[image: photo of screen]

Comment: I only mentioned the resets as its happened twice, and i don't want my pc to reset in the middle of updating.

Comment: Do you mean to upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04? Please post the error message(s) you receive. How else can we help you?

Comment: Welcome to the forum.  Please edit your question, adding the error message(s) you are getting and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: There is no 18.10.  You also mean 17.10, not 17.1.

Comment: it kept giving me the error loading repositoriies message, but it worked after 3 refreshes (closing/reopening the update center.  sorry about that if this question was a duplicate

Comment: would of made a new question, but it's the topic of update still. Also these random restarts started today, and I've had no issue with Ubuntu since I installed it from a live CD some months ago, my laptop has over 250 Gigs free on the Linux partition, and is not even a year old. I can still access grub/duelboot.

Comment: I got it to update, by remember those random resets i mentioned? Well, during these resets its as though I logged out as it doesn't reset to grub, just the login screen. during the unpacking part of the upgrade, my full~Battery Laptop did one of these resets. After the during-update reset It was locked in the login, I typed my password and it would load them send me back to the select a user screen. I turned my pc off and on, only to find the screen was flashing, and a big screen of terminal code. I turned my computer off for an hour, then on again and got same result. Flashing and all.

Comment: My screen shot will not post

Comment: look here:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-16-10-17-04-to-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu's own instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_17.10) specify how to upgrade from 17.10 on a desktop system:

Press `Alt+F2` and type  `update-manager -c`   into the command box.

Update Manager should open up and tell you that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is now available.
If not you can run  `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk`

Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score -1):

**Comment from June 2019.**
The above suggestion flat-out doesn't work any more. The *update-manager* fails to connect.
The check-new-release-gtk app fails.
You cannot even run apt-get update or apt-get upgrade and more 
Here are screenshots from trying to do all of this on a freshly installed VirtualBox VM of the ubuntu-17.10 desktop ISO

It would appear that old versions of Ubuntu and their users have simply been dumped in a ditch and abandoned. These are the links to the screenshots.

[apt-get upgrade fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEcm9.png)
[apt-get update fails, too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmQBO.png)
[check-new-release-gtk fails ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdvYN.png)
[... and then core-dumps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCFnK.png)
[update-manager also fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76H3c.png)

In summary: you can't upgrade. The best you can do is backup all your stuff, all your customisations, all your additional software configurations. Then remember all the additional software and packages you installed.
Once you've done that you have to over-write your installation with an LTS version and then spend days trying to reconfigure all the new stuff with your old settings and whatever third party software that will run on the later version.

Comment: Not true. Open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change `[countryname].archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, then change `security.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, then run `sudo apt update`, it will work. So will the upgrade to 18.

Comment: I have done some further work on this. I was able to edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file of my Ubuntu 17.10 installation and change all instances of "artful" to "bionic".

Comment: (ooops, hit RETURN too soon)
 ... Then I could perform a "apt full-upgrade" and successfully brought my Ubuntu 17.10 VM up to 18.04.
Caveat: I initially tried just performing an "apt upgrade". That appeared successful. However when I rebooted the VM, it bricked itself.

I still consider the "full-upgrade" method to be extremely brittle. One success does not imply that a different configuration would stand any chance of success