# Why does not the update work?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, 18.04

Install ubuntu 17.10 with usb in UEFI mode.
I followed the instructions for other questions on the site that I kindly offered @karel for the installation.

and as I was wrong I followed the steps that are offered in the link:
[16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)
Everything worked perfectly.
I get the complete installation and at the time of updating, it gives a series of errors that I do not have time to see, and the laptop goes to airplane mode, without starting the system.
Then update according to this question:
[How do I update Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057915/how-do-i-update-ubuntu-17-10-to-18-04)
but after finishing the installation and restarting, the screen went black and Ubuntu 18.04 did not appear.
Perform the installation again following the instructions and steps above and run the following commands:

```
sudo su;
efi = "/target/boot/efi/EFI"; \
if [[-e "$ {efi}/boot"]]; then \
echo "Backup:"; \
 mv -v "$ {efi}/boot/" "$ {efi}/boot-bak - $ (lsb_release -cs)"; \
fi; \
echo "Copy:"; \
cp -va "$ {efi}/ubuntu" "$ {efi}/boot"; \
arch = "$ (ls -1 {efi} /ubuntu/shim*.efi)"; \
arch = "$ {arch # * shim}"; \
arch = "$ {arch% .efi}"; \
cp -v "$ {efi}/boot/shim $ {arch} .efi" "$ {efi}/boot/boot $ {arch} .efi";
```

But the console gives the error:

```
cp: you can not perform "stat" on /target/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu: there is no file or directory.
```

What am I doing wrong or what I still have to do?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have spaces in all directory references an between `$ {` ? I can't find where you have the code from, but either your source is wrong or you have manged to "destroy" it. Please copy the code correctly.

Comment: If this is a path it shouldn't have spaces on either side of the / characters, e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Let's see, it comes out with spaces because I copied the code in the translator, but in the console it does not have the spaces  ....                                               I just followed the instructions that were given in the link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu